# Database analysis

Tags: sql-server, database-design, c#

I have database which that store the sold products in Orders Table and another table called Transaction
to set the time and the total price for the individual order ,my question is: How to combined more than one
order with only one Transaction number , If there is any tables that I should to create or any thing to do to 
achieve the desired result.
Thanks[image]

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're most of the way there, but the Foreign Key should go the other way around. The `Orders` table should have a FK reference to `Transaction`. This allows a Transaction to be connected to 1 or more Orders.

Comment: How I can use Transaction P.K. as a F.K. at Orders programmatically, Orders Table is filled first then will Transaction Table!

Comment: The FK can be nullable, and then when the `Transaction` is created, it can be updated.

Comment: A **Nullable FK** almost certainly indicates that the FK relationship is backward. To make a blanket statement such as you did, with out an indication of which business rules that model supports and which it doesn't, is way out of line.